# CSS: DIV containing no height on float set

Tags: css, html, height, overlap

Given the following code:

```html
<div id='upperDiv' style='min-height:200px'>
     <div id='rightDiv' style='float:right; width:75%'>
       content1
     </div>  
     <div id='leftDiv' style='float:left; width:25%'>
       content2
     </div>
</div>
<div id='lowerDiv' style='height:50px; margin-top:5px'>
   content3
</div>
```

When content of `rightDiv` and `leftDiv` passes the 200px height (the value of `min-height`), `upperDiv` does not grow, so its content overlaps the lower div.

If the float attribute is removed from the large content, it grows and causes problems.

I do not know which of `rightDiv` or `leftDiv` exceeds 200px inheight.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Set `#upperDiv` any of the following:

```
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
```

or

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
```

or create a rule using CSS pseudo-elements (IE8+ compatible) like this

```
#upperDiv:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Best solution**
Creating a reusable class rule like the following.

```
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Now you can apply it to anything that needs this same functionality. For example...

```
<div id='upperDiv' class="group" ... >
```

P.S. If you require IE 6/7 compatibility, checkout [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Answer (score 8):

This is intentional as floats are designed for things like images in paragraphs (where multiple paragraphs can wrap around the image).

Complex Spiral has a [fuller explanation](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) as to why and Ed Elliot describes a number of [approaches to making containers expand around floats](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59). I find the `overflow: hidden` approach works best in most situations.

Comment: That's a nice explanatory answer. Good links. +1

Comment: I never fully understood clearfix hacks until reading that [Complex Spiral article](http://complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/). Must read!

Answer (score 7):

After

> ```
>  <div id='leftDiv' style='float:left;width:25%;'>
>    content2
>  </div>
> ```

add

```
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new property introduced recently `display: flow-root;` Which will fix this issue without any hacks and have almost [all major support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flow-root)

```html
<div id='upperDiv' style='border: 1px solid #000000; display: flow-root;'>
     <div id='rightDiv' style='float:right;width:75%;'>
       content1
     </div>  
     <div id='leftDiv' style='float:left;width:25%;'>
       content2
     </div>
</div>
<div id='lowerDiv' style='height:50px;border: 1px solid #000000;margin-top:5px;'>
   content3
</div>
```