# h1 with "float:right" displayed incorrect css

Tags: html, css

Wonders of the web appear every day and here is the problem. I have defined h1 tag into a div class. Here is the code:

```
.menu h1
{
    width:auto;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#2e80bf;
    float:right;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I gave it **float:right;** and if the heading is 2 or more words it appear in the right as expected, but if the heading is a single word, it appear into the left side. What could be the problem?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="horizontal">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="news.php">акруално</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php">галерия</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:10px;">За Фитнес център Кеа Спорт</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.menu h1 {
  width: auto;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #2e80bf;
  float: right;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="horizontal">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="news.php">акруално</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="gallery.php">галерия</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h1 style="margin-bottom:10px;">За Фитнес център Кеа Спорт</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: display:inline-block; don't affect the situation at all...

Comment: In what browser? tested this in Chrome/Opera and IE8 on Win764 and works fine.

Comment: This works OK for me in both IE and FireFox. What DOCTYPE are you using?

Comment: doctipe is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: It appeat that way in all browsers

Comment: here you can see it in action
http://keasport.mdkbg.com/fitness.php

It's not in english click the buttons and watch the big text below the picture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you are also floating the menu above it to the right, and that this leaves enough room to the left of the menu to fit the heading when it is as narrow as one word.

Set `clear: both` on the `h1` if you don't want it to be moved up next to previous floats.

Comment: I've tried it's dispayed into the right but the heading went down to the contnent div

Comment: That is a different problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009931/css-div-height-problem-on-float-set/4009944#4009944

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on the David's advice and it works fine:

```
.menu h1
{
    width:auto;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#2e80bf;
    float:right;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    clear:right;
    }
```

Thank you all for the help