# How to align two elements in the same line,without overlap

Tags: html, css

I want to align two elements,in the same line,like this: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/a4aME/1/)

full code

```
<div id="element1">  element 1 markup </div> 
<div id="element2">  element 2 markup </div>
```

css

```
#element1 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px; 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:red;
} 
#element2 {
     display:inline-block; 
     width:200px;
     background-color:red;
}
```

Also,without overlapping each other.For example if a have a parent div,and two child divs.
The parent div,have 1000px width,and the childs have 500px each,so they fit.
But if i resize the first div to 600px,i want the second one to auto resize,and keep staying inline,without changing his position,or the first to overlap the second.
In the fiddle above,they are aligned in the same line,but doesnt matter what i do,the second one changes his position instead resizing,or they overlap each other.
Any idea?

**I know it must be done with percentage,but is not working either**

Comment: Maybe use dynamic widths, by means of percentages.

Comment: it was just an example,of course i will use percentage,but it still wont work

Comment: It doesn't work for the space between the tags. Look at my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/a4aME/507/

```
#element1 {width:50%; background-color:red;float:left} 
#element2 {width:50%; background-color:red;float:left}
```

Take off the the display: and float it all left.

Comment: and in case,the first div resize? lets say there will be an table,and user will add data,and some data will be bigger than the table.The table and the div will resize,making the second div to changing his position or overlapping each other.In this case,i need the second div to resize.

Comment: Then instead of two divs you need to set it up in a table so it handles the resize for you. Two divs will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The width attribute accepts percentage value, base on its parent (or its nearest parent with the position:relative attribute if the element has the property position set as "absolute" or "fixed").

So you can use this CSS to the child

```
#element1 {display:inline-block;margin-right:10px; width:50%; background-color:red;} 
#element2 {display:inline-block; width:50%; background-color:red;}
```

PS: If you are using inline-block, you have to make sure that there is no space between the tags, so you HTML must became this

```
<div id="element1">  element 1 markup
</div><div id="element2">
element 2 markup </div>
```

Comment: For the space beetween the #element1 and #element1, if you want you can use the solution of Nicholas Young, but you will have problem with the height of the parent. Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009931/css-div-height-problem-on-float-set

Answer (score 1):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fjy1651/) to see if it is what you wanted. I'm not using `display:inline-block` since it looks that it is what's causing the problem. If you don't mind using floats, then this is your answer.

**EDIT:**

Check this resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833734/display-inline-block-extra-margin) to see/correct your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3fjy1651/ i increased the width of the first element.What i need is,in case a div is resized,the second div must also resize,without changing its position or overlapping each other.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my fork didnt work. http://jsfiddle.net/1esn0m2t/1/ here it is.