# Divs that float within container div

Tags: html, css

I'm working with creating a series of card type objects on screen that would be in different groupings.  Within their own groups, they need to be float: left;

However, when I do this, I get them all floating regardless of their grouping.

example (in jade syntax):

```
div(ng-init="") // my angular view div
    div(class="card-container")
        div(ng-repeat="i in instance", class="card")
            p {{i.instanceName}}
    div(class="card-container")
        div(ng-repeat="d in database", class="card")
            p {{d.databaseName}}
```

So I'm hoping to have 2 divs, stacked on top of eachother in the flow.  Then within those divs, have divs that float left only within it's container div.

My css is as follows:

```
.card {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;


    display:-ms-flexbox;
    -ms-flex-pack:center;
    -ms-flex-align:center;

     /* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;

    /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;

    /* W3C */
    display:box;
    box-pack:center;
    box-align:center;
}



.card-container {
     width:100%;
}
```

Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: card container has width 100%. So do you want them row wise?

Comment: roughly.  I want them to be stacked on top of eachother, but I want the internal divs to be able to move as needed when the page is resized / viewed on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding .card-container { clear:both; }

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to `.card-container` in css:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

More info: [CSS: DIV containing no height on float set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009931/css-div-containing-no-height-on-float-set)